# Elicit slot in dialogflow for actions on google (just like ElicitSlot Directive in alexa)

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to give the user a prompt and collect a value in particular slot. Then using this slot value for this particular slot, I want to frame a next response according to this value and ask for next slot's value in line.

Now, this I can achieve in alexa quite easily with `elicitSlot` directive. But for action on google, I am not sure how to achieve this with dialogflow.

Comment: Funny, I'm facing the same issue right now. In my case, I have a decision tree that looks something like this:
`
    {
        "nodeId":
            { 
                parameter: "color",
                options: [
                    {
                        nextNode: "nodeId",
                        value: "red"
                    },
                    {
                        nextNode: "nodeId",
                        value: "blue"
                    }
               ]
            }
     }
`

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find a propery way to format code above, but the tree looks like this: https://gist.github.com/ricardocasares/110cecf5ef43838bb8d71c6228296f16

Comment: So iteratively I'm using the same intent, and asking different questions based on the current node I'm standing in. This was rather easy to do in Alexa also, but can't find a clean way to do it on google assistant without the need to have a specific context for each of my questions on the tree.

Comment: any updates? @ricardocasares

Comment: unfortunately not, couldn't find a way to achieve the same thing as ElicitSlot can do, but as a workaround, because of my decision tree has a set of common answers (Yes, No, High, Moderate, Low) I ended up grouping these categories of questions inside an intent. So I have the "boolean" intent and the "level" intent, before asking a question I set the context of what type of answer I expect to get, this matches the correct intent and then I keep track of the parameters on my own.

Comment: Well thanks for the update, but this approach in my case would certainly be not scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dialogflow's required parameters and dates.  Make each parameter you need required and move them so the order is consistent with the order in which you want Dialogflow to ask questions for you.  Then click "Define Prompt" next to the parameter you wish to create a custom response for.  In the prompt you can use any of the parameter values Dialogflow has already collected.

For instance in the sample below we are collecting the `date` and `time` parameter.  We collect the date first so that when we prompt fo the time we can use `$date` in the prompt and Dialogflow will fill in that value when asking the user for the `time` parameter.  Here is what the Dialogflow console configuration looks like:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sometimes you don't want parameters to be required, as the user might include this information or not. Think of an action that let's you search thru clothes store, you say `I want some pink(@color) trousers(@clothing)`, here user might include @color or not. Of course you could create a new intent to then ask for the color, but if you have a relatively big number of possible entities, you might want to have a way to ask for a specific parameter and match the user's answer against that specific parameter possible values. Alexa allows exactly that.

Comment: Your answer serves the problem in some cases. But I want to generate some really complex response based on the answers. This can only be achieved in a logic program.

Comment: Would love a way to elicit parameters using my own Webhook response using the app intent convo features of actions on google in nodejs.